# C# method only works on first page of ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a method which is executed when the page is loaded and when the page of the gridview is changed and then there is another method for onrowcreated. This method imports the data, as well setting the rowspans. The data import is working on every site but the Rowspan only gets set on the first page.
This is my C# Code:

```
 protected void grdvProductChurn_DataBound()
{
    for (int rowIndex = grdvProductChurn.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex += -1)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = grdvProductChurn.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = grdvProductChurn.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount <= gvRow.Cells.Count - 8; cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my asp GridView:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdvProductChurn" runat="server" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" autopostback="true"
    BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Solid" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="30" DataSourceID="DataSource_ProductChurn" 
    AllowSorting="True" ForeColor="#666666" CellSpacing="1" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,###,###}" 
    CaptionAlign="Left"  Width="960px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="GridView2"
    Height="119px" OnRowCreated="grdvProductChurn_RowCreated" onpageindexchanged="grdvProductChurn_PageIndexChanged" >
```

Then I also have the method for the onpageindexchanged. It gets executed when I change the page, but the rowspan doesn't work.

```
 public void grdvProductChurn_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdvProductChurn_DataBound();

    }
```

This is my method for OnRowCreated:

```
protected void grdvProductChurn_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "Anzahl";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 6;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
            HeaderCell.CssClass = "headercell";

            grdvProductChurn.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

        }
    }
```

On the right it looks how it is on the first page(when I go to the second page and then back to the first page it also doesn't work) And on the left it's how it looks on the second page.
[image][image]

Comment: Have you checked for IsPostBack ?

Comment: @Pushpendra Do I need to set it to true? I mean I have autopostback on true.