# C# method does something else the second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got an ASP.Net GridView which is working properly when the site  is loaded for the first time, but when I change the page in the GridView(I allowed paging) does not make the right thing but It uses the exact same mehod.
This is my method:

```
protected void grdvProductChurn_DataBound()
{
    for (int rowIndex = grdvProductChurn.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex += -1)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = grdvProductChurn.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = grdvProductChurn.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount <= gvRow.Cells.Count - 8; cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

That's the aspx:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdvProductChurn" runat="server" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Solid" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="30" DataSourceID="DataSource_ProductChurn" 
    AllowSorting="true" ForeColor="#666666" CellSpacing="1" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,###,###}" 
    CaptionAlign="Left"  Width="960px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="GridView2"
    Height="119px"    > 
    <Columns>
```

What it does:
It should put the rows together, which have the same text.
[image]
But when i change the site, it uses the same method but it doesn't put the rows together.
[image]
What I found through debugging:
On the second page the gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible is set to false from the beginning on.

Comment: what you mean `i change the site`?

Comment: Could you add the ASPX code for the gridview as well please?

Comment: Why post another question instead of editing your earlier one, found here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870861/c-sharp-method-only-works-on-first-page-of-asp-net-gridview

Comment: @Grundy I change from page1 to page2 of the GridView

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil see updated post

Comment: are you sure that on change page - you go to DataBound event again?

Comment: @Grundy I mean, It looks like it when I debug. But is it right that the DataBound event only gets executed when the site is loaded?

Comment: can you provide how you fill datasource? possibly you just need group it before and a bit fix column templates

Comment: @Grundy I just use SqlDataSource in the aspx file. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes, but i thought you use something like linq :-) can you provide columns template?

Comment: @Grundy I solved it, but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved it: 
So I called the method in the Page_Load like that:

```
grdvProductChurn_DataBound();
```

Instead I actually needed to call it like that:

```
 grdvProductChurn.DataBound += new EventHandler(grdvProductChurn_DataBound);
```

Comment: seems like you make a barrier, and then break it :-)